# What is the function of "of" between "was" and "him"?

Tags: sentence-structure

[source](http://www.freevampirenovels.com/0/2993_3.html)

> One of Cinder’s few memories of the man **was of him** being carted away
>   to the quarantines while Adri raved at how he could not leave her with
>   this thing.

I think without the "of" is coherent.

One of the memories was (him being carted ...)

PS:
Now, I know "one of the memories ... was" is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The "of" is a preposition, which is connecting "*Cinder's memories of the man*" with "*him being carted away*", indicating that the memories were *about* this happening to him.

In everyday conversation, U.S. English speakers regularly drop the "of" before "him" in this situation (*One of Cinder’s few memories of the man **was him** being carted away ...*) You would be understood either way, but it would be considered better grammar to include the "of".

Also, the use of the singular "was" is actually correct here, not the plural "were", because you are only referring to *one* of Cinder's memories.

Answer (score 0):

> One of Cinder’s few memories of the man was of him being carted away to the quarantines while Adri raved at how he could not leave her with this thing.

Cinder had several memories of the man ("a few memories of the man").
The sentence describes **one** of these memories: "a memory" (a single recollection), hence **was**, not **were**.

To simplify,

> Cinder had **a memory of the man** being carted away.

or

> Cinder **had a memory of him** being carted away.